# Random intermittent bug using next 14 and next auth - resulting in crashing on first load ( unexpected token )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, next-auth

I'm facing an error in my Next.js 14 project where I'm getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (layout.js:137) error message. This error only occurs during the initial render of the application. Subsequent reloads fixes the issue and work fine. Also important to note, in the below code the error happens very infrequently but in my prod code it happens every render.

Here's some context to help with troubleshooting:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "13",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.5",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

layout.tsx Code:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import SessionWrapper from "./components/SessionWrapper";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <SessionWrapper>
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
      </html>
    </SessionWrapper>
  );
}
```

page.tsx

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      Main page
    </main>
  );
}
```

SessionWrapper.tsx

```
"use client";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

import React from "react";

const SessionWrapper = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};

export default SessionWrapper;
```

api/auth/[...nextuaht]/route.ts

```
import KeycloakProvider from "next-auth/providers/keycloak";

import NextAuth from "next-auth";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    KeycloakProvider({
      clientId: "my id",
      clientSecret: "my secret",
      issuer: "my app",
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Expected Behavior:

The application should render successfully on the initial load without any errors.

Additional Information:
Removing tailwind seems to fix the issue ( Either from the globals.css or the postcss.config.js ) but it's hard to say 100% certain that this solves the problem and I don't understand what the underlying issue would be that would cause that

The provider is from [this](https://medium.com/@rishipardeshi/authentication-with-nextjs-14-and-next-auth-b10fe7eb6407) guide

Any help in resolving this error would be greatly appreciated!